# Find the last column of a sheet using the sheets variable name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a variable named sheet to find the last column of this sheet. My formula seems to work if I name the sheet but doesn't when I use the variable name to reference it.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim LastCol As Integer

''-------------------------------------------------''

LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox LastCol
```

This should result in column 8 being displayed but for some reason is returning 1. If I replace the 'ws' with the actual name of the sheet (as below) it works correctly.

```
LastCol = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

I'm confused as to why this isn't showing the same result.

Comment: Do you have more than one workbook open? Your first bit of code refers to ThisWorkbook, the second doesn't specify a workbook.

Comment: I’ll define ws1=“Sheet1” and then use Sheets(ws1)....

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, and suspect @SJR is correct.

Comment: Hey @SJR yes I only had one workbook open, rather bizarrely though after closing excel and re-starting it seems to work now, which sounds like I did have multiple open? Anyway thanks for your help guys

Comment: Perhaps you have a personal workbook, which is hidden usually.

Comment: @SJR the first pieces of code OP upload clearly refer to workbook as the second piece does not refer to any workbook. OP may has open 2 different workbooks at the same time causing wrong answer.

Comment: @SJR, I think it was to do with the Personal workbook, never thought of that, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Three possible solutions:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Method 1
    With ws
        LastColumn = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '<- Change number save to the row number you want to get the last column
    End With

    'Method 2
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastColumn = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    'Method 3
    LastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End Sub
```

Comment: A great answer.. but doesn't tackle OP's question. Why might the first example produce a different result to the second.